# how to combine multiple projects into one project in angular

Tags: angular, routes

I am trying to combine multiple projects into one project in angular but i am getting confused about what to write in `projects/website/src/app/app.module.ts`

This my file structure:

[image]

[This link](https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527) is the reference link for combine multiple project into one project. I'm confused about **provider part**.

Comment: it's unclear what your objective is. if you end goal is to have a single project, then just move the files into the project you want.
if you goal is to use the angular workspaces to support having multiple different projects, you can create the applications under the 'projects' directory using the "ng g application [appname]" that is mentioned in the link you added.
If the goal is to share resources between different applications, then you'll want to use libraries.

Comment: You can create multiple modules in angular, add your subprojects to the main as submodules and change the routing.